# Swiping tabs + menu crashing after some time of tapping

Tags: android

im beginner programmer and i have problem with my app. It works pretty fine, but after some time of tapping menu and swiping tabs it crashes. I'm using only ABS as external library. Feel tree to ask for code fragments you need if it's not enough. Here is logcat from crash:

```
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:819)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1890)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2139)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1476)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2087)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7535)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3415)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3347)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4456)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4538)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-28 00:17:57.461: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

@edit

Crashed my app once more and here are exception points and new log:

```
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:819)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at pl.project.schedule.TabsAdapter.onTabSelected(TabsAdapter.java:72)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarWrapper.java:356)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:587)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1084)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:537)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

--

```
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at pl.project.schedule.TabsAdapter.onTabSelected(TabsAdapter.java:72)


public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
    Object tag = tab.getTag();
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++){
        if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarWrapper.java:356)


public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mListener != null) {

                if (mFragmentTransaction == null && mActivity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
                    mFragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .disallowAddToBackStack();
                }

                mListener.onTabSelected(this, mFragmentTransaction);

                if (mFragmentTransaction != null) {
                    if (!mFragmentTransaction.isEmpty()) {
                        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                    mFragmentTransaction = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

--

```
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:587)

07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1084)


void show(boolean markHiddenBeforeMode) {
        if (mCurrentShowAnim != null) {
            mCurrentShowAnim.end();
        }
        if (mContainerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            if (markHiddenBeforeMode) mWasHiddenBeforeMode = false;
            return;
        }
        mContainerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (mShowHideAnimationEnabled) {
            mContainerView.setAlpha(0);
            AnimatorSet anim = new AnimatorSet();
            AnimatorSet.Builder b = anim.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContainerView, "alpha", 1));
            if (mContentView != null) {
                b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "translationY",
                        -mContainerView.getHeight(), 0));
                mContainerView.setTranslationY(-mContainerView.getHeight());
                b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContainerView, "translationY", 0));
            }
            if (mSplitView != null && mContextDisplayMode == CONTEXT_DISPLAY_SPLIT) {
                mSplitView.setAlpha(0);
                mSplitView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSplitView, "alpha", 1));
            }
            anim.addListener(mShowListener);
            mCurrentShowAnim = anim;
            anim.start();
        } else {
            mContainerView.setAlpha(1);
            mContainerView.setTranslationY(0);
            mShowListener.onAnimationEnd(null);
        }
    }
```

--

```
07-28 00:49:24.298: E/AndroidRuntime(11514):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:537)


   public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
   mCanceled = true;
   }
```

Comment: which line of code does the exception point to?

Comment: Crashed my app once more and added some new informations with exception points.

Comment: The exception report says null pointer exception. Do you know which line in your code is causing the null pointer exception? To do this, view the exception report and click the first file name going top to bottom that is a file you actually created/added to the project. The first step will be figuring out which exact line is the problem. Then we figure out why it is happening.

Comment: Found similar sliding menu script on internet that worked :) Thank you, Adam Jones for your help :)